# Querying SQLite in android( Summation of column values)

Tags: sql

Hi guys I want to get the summation of column values from my sqlite database in android.
and am trying to use this to get me the sum of column KEY_COST.

```
public Cursor fetchAllCost() {
   return mDb.query(
                     DATABASE_TABLE, 
                     new String[] { "SUM(KEY_COST)"}, 
                     null, 
                     null, 
                     null, 
                     null, 
                     null);
}
```

but its giving me a cursor and I do not know how to get the value from the Cursor object. Any one help!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can return scalar values like so:

```
public int getColumnData() {

    mDb = mDbManager.getReadableDatabase();
    final SQLiteStatement stmt = mDb
            .compileStatement("SELECT SUM(KEY_COST) FROM...");

    // Cast as appropriate
    return (int) stmt.simpleQueryForLong();
}
```

Or alternatively, depending on the data type use `simpleQueryForString()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should just move to the first result in the cursor with `cursor.moveFirst()` and then you can do `cursor.getInt(1)` to get the scalar value.

Answer (score 0):

**rawQuery**
Sum value is on first column - **cursor.getInt(0)**;

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(
    "SELECT SUM(" + COL_NAME + ") FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    return cursor.getInt(0);
}
```

**query**

```
String[] columns = new String[] {                
                 "sum(" + DbHelper.C_COUNT_OF_WORDS + ")"
                };

        String where = null;
        String whereArgs[] = null;
        String groupBy = null;
        String having = null;
        String order = null;
        String limit = null;

        database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.query(DbHelper.TABLE_STATISTICS, columns, where, whereArgs, groupBy, having, order, limit);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            return cursor.getInt(0);            
        }
```